# Constructing Xaml controls on C++/WinRT UI thread

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-winrt

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but even though I'm definitely on the UI thread, I'm consistently getting the error " 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.'" when constructing Xaml controls in C++.

See the following basic example, which uses a stripped down version of the default C++/WinRT CoreApplication template:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

using namespace winrt;

using namespace Windows;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Core;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Core;
using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation;

struct App : implements<App, IFrameworkViewSource, IFrameworkView> {
  CompositionTarget m_target{nullptr};

  IFrameworkView CreateView() { return *this; }

  void Initialize(CoreApplicationView const &) {}

  void Load(hstring const &) {}

  void Uninitialize() {}

  void Run() {
    CoreWindow window = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
    winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBox textbox; // Crashes here

    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = window.Dispatcher();
    dispatcher.ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessUntilQuit);
  }

  void SetWindow(CoreWindow const &) {
    Compositor compositor;
    ContainerVisual root = compositor.CreateContainerVisual();
    m_target = compositor.CreateTargetForCurrentView();
    m_target.Root(root);
  }
};

int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int) { CoreApplication::Run(make<App>()); }
```

I've tried using `window.Dispatcher().HasThreadAccess()` to verify that I'm on the correct thread to be making UI calls, and it always returns `true`.

I've also tried calling `RunAsync()` from the window's `Dispatcher` and constructing a Xaml object in a lambda passed to this method, and it still has exactly the same result. `HasThreadAccess` returns `true` here too.

Can anyone explain to me where I'm going wrong here? Is constructing Xaml objects not supported in C++?

[edit]

Here's a sample project that reproduces the issue, again based on the default CoreWindow C++/WinRT template:

https://github.com/lyptt/CoreApp1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the CoreApplication-based template does not support anything from the Xaml namespace, as it's intended more towards providing a thin UWP layer for games, etc.

To get Xaml support you need to use the full template instead, then things magically start to work.